# Как экспортировать шаблонные функции из dll?

Tags: c++, dll

Есть проблема:
Загружаю и экспортирую из dll вручную функцию (с помощью GetProcAddress()). Но эта функция шаблонная и я создаю явные специализации.

*exports.h*

```
#ifdef API_EXPORT
#    define API_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define API_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

template <class T> 
API_EXPORT T sum(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

extern "C" template API_EXPORT int sum(int a, int b);  
extern "C" template API_EXPORT float sum(float a, float b); // ERROR LNK1179 (недопустимый или поврежденный файл: повторяющийся COMDAT "_sum")
```

*exports. cpp*

```
#import "exports.h"
template API_EXPORT int sum(int a, int b);
template API_EXPORT float sum(float a, float b);
```

*main.cpp*

```
auto sum = dll.getSymbol<float (*)(float)>("sum");
```

*getSymbol:*

```
void* DynamicLibrary::getSymbol(const std::string& symbolName) const
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WIN32
    return (void*)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)instance, symbolName.c_str());
#endif
    return nullptr;
}
```

Если использовать extern "C++", то GetProcAddress находит функции по имени, но имена смотрю через банарники и выглядят они страшно).
А extern "С" разрешает только одну функцию экспортировать.

Как можно узнать имя функции, которое было сгенерировано, не заходя в бинарникик, или есть ли какой-то другой способ, как можно найти функцию ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы экспортировать несколько специализаций шаблона для каждой из них необходимо будет придумать уникальное имя (не забывайте идентификаторы в С должны быть глобально уникальными). Чтобы задать эти имена необходимо написать скрипт для линкера в том или инов виде. Для VC++ будет достаточно .def файла.

Но можно сделать и проще - экспортировать не сами специализации, а функцию, предоставляющую эти специализации:

```
enum t_SpecializationId
{
    specialization_int
,   specialization_float
...
};

extern "C" void * Fetch_Specialization(t_SpecializationId const id)
{
    void * p_result{};
    switch(id)
    {
        case specialization_int:
        {
            auto const p{&sum<int>};
            ::std::memcpy(&p_result, &p, sizeof(p_result));
            break;
        }
        ...   
    }
    return result;
}
```